# Doubt about circuits with cells having internal resistances

Tags: circuit-analysis

First take a look at the schematic diagram below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIcL6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And let's assume the the internal resistance of the cell is (r).

So here in this case E.M.F of the cell decreases, because it is given by the formula (E-ir_1) , and what I want to know is whether it is correct to use equivalent resistance between the internal resistance (r) and the other resistor(R) as (r_1), like what I have done just below

E.M.F of the cell ===> E-i(r+R)

If I assume the same thing here also, is it possible to write the E.M.F as what I have wrote above ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLb4Hx.png)</sup>

I am confused about this, I come across this problem or let's say confusion  when I am doing questions on potentiometer , so I hope it is better  to know about this which  is already get messed in my mind .

Comment: how is R2 coming into the picture?

Comment: Let's take it as an another circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes assuming V1 is a non ideal source with an internal resistance (r) in series with a load R. This can be modelled as an ideal source in series with r+R. The voltage delivered to the load will simply be \$V_r=\frac{V_1*R}{R+r}\$.

In order to operate your circuit in the linear region it is recommended that you keep R>>r.

The effective emf of the cell on the other hand may be calculated as follows assuming \$V_1\$ is an ideal source:

$$I = \frac{V_1}{R+r}$$
$$V_{eff}=V_1-(I\times r)$$

---

**EDIT 1**

For analysing the internal resistance use this model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFTMT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the effective resistance is simply r+R

**For your second circuit.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGPFt9.png)</sup>

Here in this case as you can see the effective resistance becomes (R||R2)+r

Comment: Is it okay to do so,(and could you tell me how did you enter that formula (V_R) thing , I mean the technical way you do it , still I am unable to do so

Comment: click on edit and see how i have written it.

Comment: It means I can consider it as an another resistor connected in the circuit ,right?

Comment: yes r is the internal resistance of the cell connected as another resistor in the circuit in series with the voltage source.

Comment: However your second circuit will change. R1 cannot be simplified like how you have done it.

Comment: Okay , then I could use this thing that you told just minutes ago for any circuit!

Comment: Why can't we? we can  take equivalent resistance between R1 and R2 as 50 ohms and then proceed

Comment: look at the edit

Comment: Yes , of course, any how can Iuse this for any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24203/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-sada93).